# I develp a TicTacToe game with PyQt5 and I have a problem with the vinqueur(winner)func. This func always returns 0, even if one of the players wins

Tags: python, pyqt5, tic-tac-toe, pyqt6, minmax

I am developing a TicTacToe gamebetween humin and machine(using algorithm minmax) with PyQt5 contain: def bouton (to create a grid),def vinquer(to chek the winner)def minmax and machine , Ithink i have a problem with the "vinqueur"(winner)func. This func always returns zero, even if one of the players wins.
help me please to resolv this issue.

```
%tb
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Tic_tac_toe(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300,100,400,600)  
        self.a=3
        self.Boutton()
        self.show()
        
    def Boutton(self):
        self.grille=[]
        self.joueur = -1
      
        for _ in range(self.a):
            ligne = []
            for _ in range(self.a):
                ligne.append((QPushButton(self)))
            self.grille.append(ligne)
        
        for i in range(self.a):
            for j in range(self.a):
                self.grille[i][j].setGeometry(90*i + 20,90*j + 20,80, 80)

                # setting font to the button
                self.grille[i][j].setFont(QFont(QFont('Times', 17)))

                # adding action
                self.grille[i][j].clicked.connect(self.Actions)
                

    def vinqueur(self):
        # checking if any row crossed
        for i in range(3):
            if self.grille[0][i].text() == self.grille[1][i].text() \
            and self.grille[0][i].text() == self.grille[2][i].text() \
            and self.grille[0][i].text() != "": 
                if self.grille[0][i].text() == "X":return -1
                if self.grille[0][i].text() == "O":return 1
        # checking if any column crossed
        for i in range(3):
            if self.grille[i][0].text() == self.grille[i][1].text() \
            and self.grille[i][0].text() == self.grille[i][2].text() \
            and self.grille[i][0].text() != "":
                if self.grille[i][0].text() == "X":return -1
                if self.grille[i][0].text() == "O":return 1

        # checking if diagonal crossed
        if self.grille[0][0].text() == self.grille[1][1].text() \
        and self.grille[0][0].text() == self.grille[2][2].text() \
        and self.grille[0][0].text() != "":
            if self.grille[0][0].text() == "X":return -1
            if self.grille[0][0].text() == "O":return 1

        # if other diagonal is crossed
        if self.grille[0][2].text() == self.grille[1][1].text() \
        and self.grille[1][1].text() == self.grille[2][0].text() \
        and self.grille[0][2].text() != "":
            if self.grille[0][2].text() == "X":return -1
            if self.grille[0][2].text() == "O":return 1
        return 0
        
        

    
    def Actions(self):
        
        if self.joueur==-1:
            button = self.sender()
            button.setEnabled(False)
            button.setText("X")
            self.joueur=1
        
        
        if self.joueur==1:
            self.machine()
            self.joueur=-1
            
        

        #self.tour = self.Tour() à vérifier si tu doit la remettre ou non

            # setting text to the label
            #self.label.setText(message)
    def mini_max(self, joueur):
        x=self.vinqueur()
        if x != 0:
            return x*joueur
        x,y=-1,-1
        meilleur_score=-10
        for i in range(self.a):
            for j in range(self.a):
                if self.grille[i][j].text() == "":
                    if joueur==(-1):
                        self.grille[i][j].setText("x")
                    else:self.grille[i][j].setText("o")
                    score = -self.mini_max(joueur*-1)
                    if score>meilleur_score:
                        meilleur_score = score
                        x,y=i,j
                    self.grille[i][j].setText("")
            if (x,y)==(-1,-1): return 0  

            return meilleur_score
    
    def machine(self):
        meilleur_score = -10
        x, y = -1, -1
        for i in range(self.a):
            for j in range(self.a):
                if self.grille[i][j].text() == "":
                    self.grille[i][j].setText("O")
                    score = -self.mini_max(-1)
                    self.grille[i][j].setText("")
                    if score > meilleur_score:
                        meilleur_score = score
                        x, y = i, j
        self.grille[x][y].setText("O")
        self.grille[x][y].setEnabled(False)
    
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
tic_Tac_Toe = Tic_tac_toe()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: As already told you in the other post, we don't provide debugging services. We already gave you some suggestions on how to find and eventually solve your problem. Please put more efforts in following them.

Comment: i do my maximum, i cant found the problem, its work normaly without pyqt5 but when i try to use it with pyqt5 , it doesn't work

Comment: As already suggested, start by putting some print here and there to see the current values and the validity of your "ifs"; for instance, start by checking the current state of your board and printing the results of *single* if-conditions (whether they're true or not).